# web3.js filtering events does not work

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

Event:

```
 event published(string indexed username,uint8 indexed age);
```

in front-end (browser) :

```
  instance.events                                                                                                                      
            .published(                                                                                                                      
                { fromBlock: 0, filter: { age: 15 } },                                                                                       
               function (err, evt) {                                                                                                        
                    console.log(evt);
                }                                                                                                                            
           );
```

sending values:

```
await instance.methods.publish("ezio", 15).send({ from: accounts[0] });
```

no events get captured even though the transaction is successful.
and when i use a listen to the same event with no filters i get an empty returnValues object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem it's because i was using ganache Ui, i switched to using ganache in the console and it is working fine.

PS: using `string` as an indexed parameter is wrong since you can never filter dynamic types such as string or array.